# dell server display on laptop screen

Tags: laptop, display, windows-server-2003, dell-poweredge

I have a dell server and I am trying to configure it for the first time. It is running windows server 2003. I do not have a monitor screen. Can I use laptop screen to display dell server and set it up?

I mean to say is, if I can display dell server on laptop screen, it would be great. I am trying that with a dell laptop but not getting the display.

Comment: That is a Video Out on the laptop, not an input.

Comment: Moab, not getting your point here.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Remote Desktop or VNC running on the server, you can use that.  There is no (realistic) way to connect the laptop display directly to the server.

Unless the laptop has video capture, and the server has something like an s-video out.  But it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Dell servers useally come with remote access cards. (D-RAC).

If you connect a network cable between the DRACs dedicated ethernet port and  look up the defaults for this then you can power on the server, boot the laptop and open a webpage to the DRACs address. From there you can manage the servers, including seeing its output, sending keyboard and mouse inputs (even when in the servers BIOS!) and even boot from an ISO on your laptop.